# IPN contact phone not available on subscription (subscr_signup)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

When getting a `subscr_signup` for `txn_type` I do NOT have a `contact_phone` even though the user enters it during signup (required field). Here is code:

```
$params['phone'] = $_POST['contact_phone'];
```

When I use `web_accept` the phone variable is there. I looked at the raw request from paypal and I don't see the phone number in there for subscriptions

Is this a bug or oversight?

Comment: Curious. Do you get it on the payment event? In my experience the payment and the signup events can arrive in either order, so I wait until I have them both before I do anything.

Comment: I have a 14 day trial so I cannot wait 14 days to get a phone number for the payment. Is there any other event I can use that will have the phone number? It would seem so simple to put the data in subscr_signup as I have everything else....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed with paypal that the phone number is not available in the subscr_signup. It will be in the payments.